# ¿Cómo quito yield de un código javascript para que funcione en más navegadores?

Tags: javascript

Revisando el [código de Yield prolog para JavaScript](http://yieldprolog.sourceforge.net/YieldProlog.js), un intérprete de prolog en javascript

Me encuentro que tiene muchas funciones con yield. Por ejemplo:

```
function argAssignedAll(arg1, arg2, VariableName) {
  {
    var _ArgName = arg1;
    for each (var l2 in YP.unify(arg2, Atom.NIL)) {
      if (YP.nonvar(VariableName)) {
        yield true;
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  {
    var ArgName = arg1;
    var ArgAssignments = new Variable();
    var _Calls = new Variable();
    var RestClauseBag = new Variable();
    for each (var l2 in YP.unify(arg2, new ListPair(new Functor2("f", ArgAssignments, _Calls), RestClauseBag))) {
      for each (var l3 in member(new Functor2("f", VariableName, ArgName), ArgAssignments)) {
        for each (var l4 in argAssignedAll(ArgName, RestClauseBag, VariableName)) {
          yield false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

El problema es que no todos los navegadores soportan yield aún, pues es parte de `EcmaScript 3.1`, quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de convertir estas funciones a un código que sea aceptado por más navegadores.

Pueden ver el código en acción en: http://yieldprolog.sourceforge.net/queryEditor.html

Situacion ideal: que funcione en el navegador nativo de `android`.

Comment: creo que la libreria es muy vieja, en el js dice que es 2007 2008 puede que mas bien las funciones te esten dando problemas

Comment: @JackNavaRow y el problema es que no todo el js es estándard, pero un problema a la vez.

Answer (score 3):

Te recomiendo que uses [babel](http://babeljs.io) para que te convierta ese código a EcmaScript 5.

Básicamente lo que hacen es usar un transformador llamado [regenerator](https://github.com/facebook/regenerator) para que convierta todas las ocurrencias de esa instrucción en código que puede ser ejecutado por versiones anteriores del navegador.

Ten en cuenta que el [soporte para EcmaScript 5](http://caniuse.com/es5) en versiones antiguas de Android es sólo parcial así que tendrás que probar si funcionan como se espera. Sólo hasta la versión 4.4 se considera completamente soportado.

Comment: @Ruslan López Carro No te olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió

Comment: no me sirve porque el código del yield prolog no es estándard, así que babel no me sirve (adicionalmente de que no quiero descargar la enciclopedia británica IYKWIM) .

Comment: @RuslanLópez "código del yield prolog no es estándard", Esto no tiene sentido. si corre en un navegador y es código javascript a menos que la propia documentación te especifique que debas pre-procesarlo primero de alguna manera pues entonces ES estándar por la sencilla razón que el navegador no sabe interpretar otra cosa que no sea javascript.

Comment: no corre en un navegador normal, no es estándard porque no es Ecmascript. Se puede correr únicamente en ciertas versiones de cierto navegador que aceptan un JS no estándard. Además de que la pregunta es acerca de yield, no de todo el código de la librería.

Comment: @RuslanLópez Si la librería se adhiere a cierto comportamiento no estándar de ciertos navegadores implementado en un período corto de tiempo entonces lo que necesitas es que la librería se actualice o usar otra librería. Por que razón aceptarías usar un código que sabes que no perdurará en el futuro? No hace eso las cosas mucho más difíciles para ti?

Comment: como te imaginarás por razones personales estoy migrando yo mismo la librería a typescript, pero el soporte para `yield` no estaba listo en ese momento. Y disculpa, pero tu respuesta por la misma razón es totalmente irrelevante.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías llamar otra función con un return a la función principal (Es un poco lioso pero creo que funcionaría).
Al ser tan liosa la respuesta, no creo que sea conveniente, pero igual si te sirve te la dejo por aquí:

```js
function funcionPrincipal(variable) {
  if (variable) {
    console.log(variable);
  } else {
  funcionConYield();
  }
}

function funcionConYield() {
  //yield 2;
  funcionParaYield(2);
}

function funcionParaYield(parametro) {
  funcionPrincipal(parametro);
}
funcionPrincipal();
```